# Substract 2 columns from postgreSQL LEFT JOIN query with NULL values

Tags: database, postgresql, join

I have a postgreSQL query which should be the actual stock of samples on our lab.
The initial samples are taken from a table (tblStudies), but then there are 2 tables to look for to decrease the amount of samples.
So I made a union query for those 2 tables, and then matched the uniun query with the tblStudies to calculate the actual stock.
But the union query only gives values when there is a decrease in samples.
So when the study still has it's initial samples, the value isn't returned.
I figured out I should use a JOIN operation, but then I have NULL values for my study with initial samples.

Here is how far I got, any help please?

```
SELECT
    "tblStudies"."Studie_ID", "SamplesWeggezet", c."Stalen_gebruikt", "SamplesWeggezet" - c."Stalen_gebruikt" as "Stock"
FROM
    "Stability"."tblStudies"
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT b."Studie_ID",sum(b."Stalen_gebruikt") as "Stalen_gebruikt"
        FROM (
            SELECT "tblAnalyses"."Studie_ID", sum("tblAnalyses"."Aant_stalen_gebruikt") AS "Stalen_gebruikt"
            FROM "Stability"."tblAnalyses"
            GROUP BY "tblAnalyses"."Studie_ID"
            UNION 
            SELECT "tblStalenUitKamer"."Studie_ID", sum("tblStalenUitKamer".aant_stalen) AS "stalen_gebruikt"
            FROM "Stability"."tblStalenUitKamer"
            GROUP BY "tblStalenUitKamer"."Studie_ID"
        ) b
        GROUP BY b."Studie_ID"
    ) c ON "tblStudies"."Studie_ID" = c."Studie_ID"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing a LEFT JOIN to the inline query "C" some values of `c."stalen_gebruikt"` can be null. And any number - null is going to yield null. To address this we can use coalesce

So change

`"samplesweggezet" - c."stalen_gebruikt" AS "Stock`

to

`"samplesweggezet" - COALESCE(c."stalen_gebruikt",0) AS "Stock`

Comment: Thanks, that did the job.
I didn't know about the COALESCE function